# error syncing protractor after clicking on navigation

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

There's a number of posts about `Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page`, but I think this is something different.

Setup:
I have a form on a page with angular. The form does a POST, which redirects to another page (let's call this the submission page) also with angular. The submission is triggered via an `element().click()`

I get intermittent `Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page` issues after the submission is triggered. Not every time, maybe 1/4 of the time.

---

Edit: relevant test code

```
// fill out form
element(by.css('.submit-btn')).click()
browser.wait(waitForUrl(), 5000)

// errors somewhere around here
expect(element(by.css('h1')).getText()).toMatch('Form submitted')
// errors somewhere around here

function waitForUrl() {
  return browser.getCurrentUrl().then(function(url) {
    return /submitted/.test(url)
  })   
}
```

After digging around, I'm thinking there's a race condition because some test actions are ran before angular is loaded on the submission page.

I've tried `browser.waitForAngular()` to no avail. `browser.ignoreSynchronization` works, but since there is angular on the submission page this is not ideal. I'm really hoping `browser.waitForAngular()` would do what it seems to supposed to do - wait for angular to be loaded, but doesn't seem to do so unless I'm doing this wrong.

Comment: Could you show the related part of your test where the form submission is done and what happens next? Thanks.

Comment: Done @alecxe. Also FWIW, I've been reading the protractor source: https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/protractor.js. It seems like browser.get() does some angular module mocking and other complicated things + waits for angular (but different than browser.waitForAngular I think?)

Comment: Thanks! `by.css('h1')` probably should be smth like `element(by.css('h1')).getText()`? Also, I think there is a timeout value missing in the `browser.wait()` call..Also, what if you would explicitly resolve the `click()` and put the rest of the code into the promise resolution callback: `element(by.css('.submit-btn')).click().then(function () { // the rest of the code here });`?

Comment: Sorry, stripped out too much code. Yeah I'll try the promise resolution.